# Discord.py command just stops working after a few times?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

Here is my command:

```
@bot.command()
async def cg(ctx, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None, arg4=None, arg5=None):
try:
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if arg1:
        new_name = arg1
        try:
            new_name = new_name + " " + arg2
        except:
            pass
        try:
            new_name = new_name + " " + arg3
        except:
            pass
        try:
            new_name = new_name + " " + arg4
        except:
            pass
        try:
            new_name = new_name + " " + arg5
        except:
            pass
        new_name = new_name.title()
        new_name = "Current Game: " + new_name
        await channel.edit(name=new_name)
    else:
        await ctx.send("I need a channel name.")
except:
    await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
```

It's meant to change the name of whatever voice channel the user is in. This will work a few times, and then just stop working. No error messages or anything, and I found out that it stops at the "await channel.edit(name=new_name)" using lots of prints.

For example, I could name it "Test" one time and it would work. Then, I name it "Test Name," but it stops working. Then, if I try "Test" again, it doesn't work. I'm not sure why it's not working when there's no error messages in console. The custom error messages to send in Discord do work, though.

Comment: Do you have a error exception command?

Comment: no, i con't believe so

Comment: Delete the `try-except` part so see the error.

Comment: BTW you may want to take a look here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable